# How to place button at the middle left of background image?

Tags: html, css, button, background, position

Here's my button: http://jsfiddle.net/cRqhT/120/

HTML:

```
<a id="button" href="http://example.com"</a>
```

CSS:

```
#button{
  display: block;
    width: 121px;
    height: 40px;
    background: url(https://gator1174.hostgator.com/~mskparik/facebook/1.png) no-repeat top;
}
#button:hover {
    background: url(https://gator1174.hostgator.com/~mskparik/facebook/2.png) no-repeat bottom;
    }
```

Here's background: http://b.dryicons.com/files/graphics_previews/shining_background.jpg

How do I place my button over background in the middle left?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear and not useful

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a > from your anchor:

```
<a id="button" href="http://mysite.com"></a>
```

One solution would be to put your anchor in a container with that background and absolute position the anchor:

```
<div>
    <a ... ></a>
</div>


.div { position:relative; background:transparent url('myUrl.png') no-repeat; }
a { position:absolute; top:XXpx; left:0; }
```

Where the divider has the same height and width as the background image, and `XXpx` is equal to the anchor's height subtracted from the image height, divided by two.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cRqhT/121/).